# listview with different cell height

Tags: java, listview, javafx

I'm trying to do a `ListView` in which the selected cell has a different UI (and a different height, respectively). The cells are declared in `FXML` and custom controls (`DisplayRowDefault` and `DisplayRowSelected`) are created that load the corresponding `FXML` files.

I also have a cell factory set up where I manage the rendering of the cell, depending on whether it is selected or not.

```
listView.setCellFactory(lv -> new ListCell<>() {
        private DisplayRowSelected selectedGraphics;
        private DisplayRowDefault defaultGraphics;

        {
            defaultGraphics = new DisplayRowDefault();
            selectedGraphics = new DisplayRowSelected();
        }

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(Item item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);

            if(empty || item == null) {
                setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);
                setGraphic(null);
            }
            else {
                selectedGraphics.setIndex(getListView().getItems().indexOf(item));
                selectedGraphics.setItem(item);

                setGraphic(isSelected() ? selectedGraphics : defaultGraphics);
                setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Everything works "perfectly" except that the cell size remains the same.

**edit:** I found a solution to the problem. When override `computePrefHeight` cells are resized correctly. The disadvantage of this method is that the prefHeight must be explicitly specified.

```
listView.setCellFactory(lv -> new ListCell<>() {
        private DisplayRowSelected selectedGraphics;
        private DisplayRowDefault defaultGraphics;

        {
            defaultGraphics = new DisplayRowDefault();
            defaultGraphics.setPrefHeight(50);

            selectedGraphics = new DisplayRowSelected();
            selectedGraphics.setPrefHeight(100);
        }

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(Item item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);

            if(empty || item == null) {
                setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);
                setGraphic(null);
            }
            else {
                selectedGraphics.setIndex(getListView().getItems().indexOf(item));
                selectedGraphics.setItem(item);

                setGraphic(isSelected() ? selectedGraphics : defaultGraphics);
                setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
            }

            setPrefHeight(Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE);
        }

        @Override
        protected double computePrefHeight(double v) {
            if(getContentDisplay() == ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY) {
                return isSelected() ? selectedGraphics.getPrefHeight() : defaultGraphics.getPrefHeight();
            }

            return super.computePrefHeight(v);
        }
    }
);
```

**edit:** MCVE

```
public class Sample extends Application {
    private class SelectedCell extends VBox {
        public SelectedCell() {
            getChildren().add(new Label("---"));
            getChildren().add(new Label("Selected Cell"));
            getChildren().add(new Label("---"));
        }
    }

    private class DefaultCell extends VBox {
        public DefaultCell() {
            getChildren().add(new Label("Default Cell"));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        List<String> items = List.of("Item A", "Item B", "Item C", "Item D");

        ListView<String> listView = new ListView<>();
        listView.getItems().setAll(items);

        listView.setCellFactory(lv -> new ListCell<>() {
            private SelectedCell selectedCell = new SelectedCell();
            private DefaultCell defaultCell = new DefaultCell();

            @Override
            protected void updateItem(String s, boolean b) {
                super.updateItem(s, b);

                if(s == null || b) {
                    setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);
                    setGraphic(null);
                }
                else {
                    setGraphic(isSelected() ? selectedCell : defaultCell);
                    setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
                }
            }
        });

        Scene scene = new Scene(listView, 200, 500);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't take a deep look, but on the surface, it looks like [this](http://fxexperience.com/2010/04/dynamic-cell-sizes/#targetText=When%20cells%20are%20laid%20out,it'll%20be%20100px%20tall.) may help.

Comment: @kleopatra, ready

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments this might be a bug (or not - a cell has many properties and their interplay is not completely specified). Hacky workarounds - here: triggering fake edit transitions or manually setting the height - often are needed.

The fact that a fake edit transition on listening to the selected property hacks the problem indicates that we need to update the graphic "earlier" (than updateItem) in the change notification chain, that is when the selected changes:

- the method to hook into (instead of manually listening) is `updateSelected(boolean)`
- override and change the graphic as needed

A code snippet:

```
@Override
public void updateSelected(boolean selected) {
    super.updateSelected(selected);
    setGraphic(selected ? selectedCell : defaultCell);
}



@Override
protected void updateItem(String s, boolean b) {
    super.updateItem(s, b);

    if(s == null || b) {
        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);
        setGraphic(null);
    }
    else {
        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
        setGraphic(isSelected() ? selectedCell : defaultCell);
    }
}
```

to override the cell's updateSelected(boolean) method and set the cell's graphic as needed:

Comment: simple and elegant solution.

Comment: thanks :) Wouldn't have touched the problem without [mcve], glad you provided one eventually <g>. A very minor note: would prefer a self-answer to stick to the self-provided example - makes it easier to test the solution by simple c&p (vs. having to edit the field names). Yeah, I'm extremely lazy ..

Answer (score 2):

Although the solution by explicitly asking `prefHeight` (which I mentioned in the question) works, it is not a good solution. The reason for this is that the dimensions of the individual `Node`s depend on the context in which they are placed. So, a `prefHeight` value cannot always be determined.

By design, `ListView` is designed so that in edit mode, cells use a different UI, and changing modes causes the cell size to be correctly re-calculated. So I choose the approach where I start/stop editing the current cell when changing the selection.

This is the solution I found and it works correctly:

```
public class Sample extends Application {
    private class SelectedCell extends VBox {
        public SelectedCell() {
            getChildren().add(new Label("---"));
            getChildren().add(new Label("Selected Cell"));
            getChildren().add(new Label("---"));
        }
    }

    private class DefaultCell extends VBox {
        public DefaultCell() {
            getChildren().add(new Label("Default Cell"));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        List<String> items = List.of("Item A", "Item B", "Item C", "Item D");

        ListView<String> listView = new ListView<>();
        listView.getItems().setAll(items);

        listView.setEditable(true);

        listView.setCellFactory(lv -> new ListCell<>() {
            private SelectedCell selectedCell = new SelectedCell();
            private DefaultCell defaultCell = new DefaultCell();

            {
                selectedProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                    if (oldValue != null && oldValue) {
                        cancelEdit();
                    }

                    if (newValue != null && newValue) {
                        startEdit();
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void startEdit() {
                super.startEdit();
                setGraphic(selectedCell);
            }

            @Override
            public void cancelEdit() {
                if(!isSelected()) {
                    super.cancelEdit();
                    setGraphic(defaultCell);
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void updateItem(String s, boolean b) {
                super.updateItem(s, b);

                if(s == null || b) {
                    setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);
                    setGraphic(null);
                }
                else {
                    setGraphic(isEditing() ? selectedCell : defaultCell);
                    setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
                }
            }
        });

        Scene scene = new Scene(listView, 200, 500);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm .. good that you found a workaround :) Though, wondering how the misbehavior could happen even if the list is not editable (as in your example in the question). Smells like a bug to me (there used to be problems when updating the ui in updateItem when a property - other than item, f.i. selected - is changed. It's fixed, this might be a left-over)

Comment: indeed working, the fake editable change seems to trigger a "broader" relayout of the list than an selected change (definitely a bug in my book) - to make it work for not editable lists, updateItem should stick to selected property to decide which graphic to set (otherwise the height is updated but not the content, looks like a instable layout)